# How can I check if 3 out of 5 integer are the same

Tags: c#, integer

Let's say I have 5 integers.

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int c = 5;
int d = 1;
int f = 1;
```

I want to check if any of these 3 out of 5 integers are the same.

I've tried some stuff however it got very long (500+ lines) and thought this wasn't a good method to use.

Comment: Do you need to know which ones are the same or just want to know where there are some which are same?

Comment: I only need to know if some of them are.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

first put them all in a single collection, rather than having separate variables:

```
var numbers = new[]{a,b,c,d,f};
```

Then group them, find the count of each group, and see if anything meets your criteria.

```
var isLargeGroup = numbers.GroupBy(n => n, (key, group) => group.Count() )
    .Any(count => count >= 3);
```

Comment: it doesn't compile. `The type arguments for method ... cannot be inferred from the usage.Try specifying type argument explicitly`

Comment: @Selman22 Right.  I always assume that the second parameter's delegate should just have an `IGrouping` parameter.  It would make the world so much easier.  Sadly it doesn't.  Trivial fix though.

Comment: @キャタ I did, in the post iteself.  It also reads pretty much like what it does.  Group all of the items in the collection based on each number, then map each group into it's count (this is what the second parameter to `GroupBy` is doing).  Finally, if Any of those counts are greater than or equal to three, it will be true, else false.

Comment: This is a potentially expensive (for large sets of numbers), inefficient answer that creates a lot of objects and does a full enumeration of the set.

Comment: @DavidHaney The big oh of this is identical to yours.  The only real difference is that this doesn't short circuit.  How expensive that is is of course going to depend on how far into the set you find the 3rd item (if there even are 3 equal items).  In most situations this isn't going to be a dramatic difference.

Comment: @Servy The Big O is not the same, due to your `Count()` of the enumerated grouping. Aside of Big O, the cost in terms of created handles for objects which will later be garbage collected is not trivial.

Comment: @DavidHaney Counting the size of the groups is going to be an O(1) operation given the fact that `group` is an `ICollection`, so the optimization in `Count` that lets it quickly grab the count will take effect, but even if that *weren't* the case, both solutions would *still* be O(n).  After all, O(2*n) equals O(n/2).  As for the garbage collection, that actually *will* be trivial.  Allocating an object that doesn't survive even a single GC has virtually no cost at all.  It's keeping objects alive through a collection that has a cost.  Not that there are *that* many objects created here.

Comment: @Servy - You have no guarantee that the allocation would not be promoted and I suspect you KNOW this since you know your stuff... If the group by was long running for example, you'd suffer some Gen 1 or 2 for it. Also the optimization in `Count()` is exactly my point: nice, quick code is better than enumerating. Man, we bash heads a lot. Would like to have a beer or coffee some time. :)

Comment: @DavidHaney Technically you cannot guarentee it, no, but while there are a fair number of objects created, there are not a lot of objects all alive at the same time.  A handful of objects might live through a GC, but a large number will not (due to the streaming nature of LINQ) so the performance impact of a GC happening to run while this is running (which is in itself unlikely) is not going to be very great.

Answer (score 1):

Both of the other solutions are potentially expensive for large sets (say 10000 numbers), costing a full enumeration and creating many objects which will be garbage collected. Try this, which could stop execution long before a complete enumeration:

```
private bool AreNumbersTheSame(int[] numbers, int duplicateCount)
{
    var numberCounts = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
    {
        var current = numbers[i];
        if (!numberCounts.ContainsKey(current))
        {
            numberCounts[current] = 1;
            continue;
        }

        if (numberCounts[current] == duplicateCount - 1)
        {
            return true;
        }

        numberCounts[current]++;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Call it like:

```
var result = AreNumbersTheSame(new[] { a, b, c, d, f }, 3);
```

Comment: With a collection of size 5, I think fully iterating it without short circuiting is feasible.

Comment: With collection of size 5000, not so much.

Comment: But the question *specifically* says that it is of size 5.

Comment: Fair enough. Nobody has to upvote me. It feels like efficiency is a dead art these days, slain by the costly misuse of LINQ. :)

Comment: premature optimization is the root of all evil.  It's important to realize what is, and is not, worth optimizing.  You need to take the time to recognize what optimizations are making enough of a difference to be worth the developer time, as well as added code complexity.  Here, the performance difference is virtually zero, given the small data set.  Code clarity, and obvious correctness, is far more valuable then the handful of microseconds difference there would be between these solutions.

Comment: I've overlooked your approach somehow. Very similar to mine. So +1 from me.

Comment: @Servy - while I fully agree with that, this is not a premature optimization. This is how a loop is written pre-LINQ. LINQ is not a one-size-fits-all solution, and IGroupings are not super intuitive for new developers either - even if they know SQL GROUP BY or similar lambda calculus. The reality is that such an optimization as this is EASIER to read to me, and took me about 30 seconds longer than a GROUP BY would have. And knowing the inner workings of the .NET runtime and GC, I'd take this over that large object creating LINQ any day. You can do as you please; my means serve me well.

Comment: @DavidHaney You stated that the reason you felt this was worth using before was because of performance, and that "efficiency is a dead art these days, slain by the costly misuse of LINQ".  Stating that the performance improvement here is relevant is simply not true.  Both solutions will easily complete in an astoundingly short period of time, rendering optimizations moot.  If you find this solution more readable, then that's an entirely different point, one that is much more subjective.  You also seem to, in general, have an exaggerated image of the costs associated with LINQ.

Comment: @Servy: i also fully agree with you that premature optimization should be avoided. But apart from the performance aspect, if something is worth to be buried in an extension method since it's very likely that i (or others) will use it often, i can invest more time to optimze the code inside. Readability is also less important if the extension is tested and has a meaningful name and documentation.

Comment: @TimSchmelter That makes the assumption that this is an operation performed so frequently that it's worth the time and effort to write a generalized library method to perform it.  You happened to make that assumption, which is fine, if you have reason to believe it to be the case.  I made the assumption that this was a one off request not worth taking the time and effort to put into a general purposed, optimized, heavily tested, library.  If it so happened that this was something I found myself using frequently, demonstrating a need for that, I'd likely take the time to do it.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, here's another option which is less elegant than `GroupBy` but more efficient if the sequence is large. Hidden in an extension method readability is not so important in my opinion.

```
public static bool HasDuplicateCount<T>(this IEnumerable<T> seq, int maxCount)
{
    Dictionary<T, int> counts = new Dictionary<T, int>();
    foreach (T t in seq)
    {
        int count;
        if (counts.TryGetValue(t, out count))
            ++count;
        else
            count = 1;
        if (count == maxCount)
            return true;
        counts[t] = count;
    }
    return false;
}
```

You can use it in this way:

```
bool threeDups = new[] { a, b, c, d, f }.HasDuplicateCount(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also be solved using the [Majority Vote](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~moore/best-ideas/mjrty/example.html) algorithm, as long as you are looking to see if more than half of your elements are the same (as is the case for 3 out of 5 elements):

```
public static bool HasMajorityElement(int[] a)
{
    int candidate = 0;
    int count = 0;
    foreach (int i in a)
    {
        if (count == 0)
        { 
            candidate = i;
            count = 1;
        }
        else 
        {
            count += candidate == i ? 1 : -1;
        }
    }
    count = 0;
    foreach (int i in a)
    {
        if (i == candidate) ++count;
    }
    return count > a.Length / 2;
}
```

[Test it](http://ideone.com/1hwN3Q) on ideone.com.

Or alternatively for your specific case:

```
public static bool ThreeOutOfFive(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e)
{
    return ((a==b?1:0)+(a==c?1:0)+(a==d?1:0)+(a==e?1:0) > 1)
        || ((b==c?1:0)+(b==d?1:0)+(b==e?1:0) > 1)
        || ((c==d?1:0)+(c==e?1:0) > 1);
}
```

Comment: Interesting. But solves a different problem. OP just wants to know if there is a duplicate in the array that repeats at least three times. So if the array would contain 6 numbers instead with three duplicates your method would return the wrong result(false instead of true).

Comment: True, but the OP specifically asks for 3 out of 5. I've added clarification that you have to be looking for more than half of your elements to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following :-

1. Add all the numbers to a list.
2. Create a dictionary having number as the KEY and its occurrence as VALUE.
3. While iterating the list, need to check if a number is not in dictionary then add it using number as the KEY and 1 as its VALUE.
4. If the number re-occurs, just increment the dictionary VALUE by 1.
5. Once it is equal to 3, break out of the loop.

   ```
           int a = 1;
           int b = 2;
           int c = 5;
           int d = 1;
           int f = 1;
           var listOfNumbers = new List<int> {a, b, c, d, f};

           var dict = new Dictionary<int, int>();
           foreach (var number in listOfNumbers)
           {
               if (dict.ContainsKey(number))
               {
                   dict[number] = dict[number] + 1; //if a key repeats => increment the value by 1
                   if (dict[number] == 3)
                       break; //found the number
               }
               else
                   dict.Add(number, 1); //for first occurence of the key => initialize the value with 1 
           }
   ```